# Swift "show segue" is not available when Ctrl Drag a button on View Controller

Tags: ios, xcode, segue

I'm having a very hard time here.

I created an iOS App in which I have a Navigation controller and a main screen showing a device list and now I'd like to add a detailed view. My issue is, I can't create a segue with action "Show" - the Interface Builds in Xcode only provides options "Push", "Modal" and "Custom"

I'm an absolute beginner in Swift (or for that Apple) development and each and every tutorial I found with google, says, I'd simply have to Ctrl-Click the button, drag it to the new view controller and choose "show" - but there is no :-(

I'm attaching a picture, so you might see more clearly. [image: Screenshot trying to create action]

Please, if someone could help me out here.

Is my problem caused by choosing Single View Application in the project???

I'm using Xcode 8, Swift 3 and developing for iOS 10 on iPhone

Comment: single view has nothing to do with your problem. do you have any breakpoints you may have accidentally placed?

Comment: turn on the size class to access to the full segues menus. @siliconchris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely using the old Xcode storyboard layout, to go back to modern layout:

select `Main.storyboard`, go to `file inspector` and check the `Use Auto Layout` and `Use Trait Variations` boxes.

[image]

Comment: OmG - can it be that easy? Why exactly is a fixed layout setting interfering with actions? As said, I'm a complete newbie

Comment: Hey @ldan - this worked, but actually only after I also activated the second option "Use Trait Variations" also.

Comment: You are right, `Use Trait Variation` is actually the source of your issue. These two do go together (edited the answer). As to why? I'm not sure, I think it's just the way Xcode evolved (maybe different question).

Comment: The icon to select as shown in the image is correct, however it is called 'file inspector' not 'identity inspector'